# Django - how get last item from queryset in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm a complete beginner at Django and can't do something quite basic; link to the last (or first) item in the database.

To start with this is the model I'm working with:

```
class Artwork(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    art = models.ImageField(upload_to='artworks/%Y')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    herochoices = [('left', 'left'), ('middle', 'middle'), ('right', 'right')]
    hero = models.CharField(choices=herochoices, max_length=6, null=True, blank=True, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':'Another artwork already uses this hero position.'})  
    slug = slugify(title, allow_unicode=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_urls(self):
        return reverse('artwork_list', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

I created the following queryset in my view:

```
class ArtworkDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Artwork
    template_name = 'artwork_detail.html'
    qs = Artwork.objects.all()
```

And now inside my template I'm trying to provide a link to the last item in the queryset. However I have no idea what to populate the href attribute with in order to provide such link:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>{{ artwork.title|title}}</h1>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-1 float-left">
            <p class="arrows">
                {% if artwork.get_previous_by_date.id == '' %}
                        <a href="{{ ????? }}">
                {% else %}
                    <a href="/artwork/{{ artwork.get_previous_by_date.id }}/{{ artwork.get_previous_by_date.title }}/">
                {% endif %}
                    <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 30pt">keyboard_arrow_left</span>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

I have tested that the if condition works fine by putting a url to https://www.google.com in there which works fine. My problem really is with getting the absolute url of the last item in the queryset into my template.

Thank you,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the `.latest(…)` or `.last()` by overriding the `get_object` method:

```
class ArtworkDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Artwork
    template_name = 'artwork_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryet=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        return queryset.latest('date')
```

Or you can use a dedicated method:

```
class ArtworkDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Artwork
    template_name = 'artwork_detail.html'

    def latest_artwork(self):
        return Artwork.objects.latest('date')
```

and render it in the view with:

```
<a href="{{ view.latest_artwork.get_absolute_url }}">
```

Note that you made a typo in you model, it is `get_absolute_url`, not <s>`get_absolute_urls`</s>.

Comment: Hi Willem, thank you so much, that second solution worked like a charm. I modified the href value a bit because I currently have an issue with the slug not working, but I fix that another time. Thank you so much, for the clean solution and for pointing out the typo in my model as well.